# Does it make sense to remove NFS from a simple web server?

Tags: security, performance, nfs

Does it make sense security- and performance-wise to remove NFS on a simple server which has ~10 Wordpress websites? Or is simply stopping the services enough?

Comment: Why is it installed in the first place if you don't need it?

Comment: I have read that it is installed by default in Debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From security perspective I believe these would likely be the same. If the service is stopped, the port will be closed and will reject connections. You probably also want to make sure that your firewall rules block access to the NFS ports as well. That said, uninstalling would mean you couldn't accidentally/inadvertently restart the service.

From a performance perspective, it depends on what type of bottleneck you're concerned with. if the service is stopped, it's not consuming memory or processing resources, but it's still using a small amount of disk space to store program and configuration files.

Also, there may come a time when you need to use it to administer the server, so keeping it around but disabled might save you some time in the future.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Can you tell me in what scenarios I would need it to administer the server?

Comment: Realistically, you probably won't. But perhaps if you needed someone else (possibly untrustworthy) to upload some file or data but didn't want to give them login credentials, you could throw up the service temporarily for them to upload and then take it back down.

Comment: Perfect - just wanted to make sure I wouldn't mess anything up by uninstalling. Thanks for the help!